# How to run a .cpp file with Gecode Framework on Linux?

Tags: c++, gecode

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and try to compile the example 'money.cpp' file that Gecode brings. I downloaded (gecode-release-5.1.0.tar.gz) and extract it. Then to install Gecode I do the following steps:

(1) ./configure
(2) make

I get satisfactory installation.

Then I try to compile money.cpp, like this:
$g++ money.cpp

and I get the following error:

fatal error: gecode / driver.hh: No such file or directory
  #include 
           ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I know the problem is that it does not recognize the libraries, but how can I make my .cpp or compile phase recognize them?

regards!
Alberto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call g++ with the `-I` flag so that g++ knows where to look for the include files:

```
g++ -I<dir> money.cpp
```

`<dir>` is the source code directory for the files (the one with structure as seen on GitHub):

```
https://github.com/Gecode/gecode
```

See *Compiling with g++*:

```
https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse373/99au/unix/g++.html
```

Comment: Hello Luis D, I put 'g++ -Igecode  examples/money.cpp' or 'g++ -I/home/ripi/Desktop/gecode-release-5.1.0/gecode  examples/money.cpp' and I get the same error: fatal error: gecode/driver.hh, I'm missing something??

Comment: @GMs, You would have to use `g++ -I${GECODE_INSTALL_DIR} money.cpp`. -I allows you to include header files from other directories/projects.